# can i overwrite or fully delete an !important with another line of code?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

so i stated working on a website which already had a strong base and code so i just wanted to make that one better. but there was a twist.
the site had a lot of !important and for some reason i dont have access to that part/cant find it. and when i try to overwrite it in another line for some other stuff on the website another part of the site breaks. so is there any way that i can make that go away with an added line ?

it is on wordpress btw and thats why im saying i dunno where/how to find that line of code.

Comment: Are those `!important` rules inline styles or in a different css file?

Answer (score -1):

Yes... You can override it by adding another CSS code with the !important rule but with higher specificity.
Let's say the !important is applied to a class and you want to override it, you should simply create another rule with the !important tag but this time around, use it on the id of the element that you are overriding because it has higher specificity than the class.
Here's a link to an article that you can read through incase you don't understand or want to read more about this topic.

[https://blog.hubspot.com/website/css-important#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20ways%20you,selector%20with%20a%20higher%20specificity](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/css-important#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20ways%20you,selector%20with%20a%20higher%20specificity).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).